# а возможно ли создать список в opencv для отличий лиц

Tags: python, opencv

```
import face_recognition

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
face_locations = []
cv2.namedWindow("test")

img_counter = 0

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]
    if not ret:
        print("failed to grab frame")
        break
    cv2.imshow("test", frame)
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)
    for top, right, bottom, left in face_locations:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('test', frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k%256 == 27:
        # ESC pressed
        print("Escape hit, closing...")
        break

cam.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Это мой код. Я хочу, чтоб у меня была локальная база данных, которая будет писать моё имя рядом с синим квадратом.